# Spring boot - Why is the exclude required when manually configuring Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a following Spring boot project which uses Spring data JPA. My rest controller is annotated with the the following annotations-:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({ "com.foo.bar"})
public class RESTService {
```

My question is why is the exclude parameter required in the @EnableAutoConfiguration ? If I start the application without the exclude I get the following exceptions-:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Now I am manually configuring Hibernate from within my project.

My reasoning is that since Spring Boot sees spring data on the class path it tries to autoconfigure JDBC and Hibernate JPA. But then why isn't it trying to autoconfigure Mongo or any other data base solution ?

Can someone please help me to understand what is going on here ?

My POM file is-:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>REST Service</name>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.fosstrak.epcis</groupId>
                <artifactId>epcis-repository</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
             -->
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.fosstrak.epcis</groupId>
                <artifactId>epcis-repository</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/epcis-commons-0.5.0.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.foo.bar.RESTService</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                  </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you please post your pom file? @SpringBootApplication should be put on the main application class. Is the RESTService class your main class?

Comment: @MrKiller21 Added my POM file

Comment: Spring Boot will only configure what it finds on the class path. If you don't have mongo why would it need to configure mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring only autoconfigures Mongo if you have the respective starter dependency in your classpath.

For example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Regarding the Exception you postet, it says that you havn't configured your Databasedriver. You need someting along those lines in your properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<schema>
spring.datasource.username: <user>
spring.datasource.password: <password>
```

Depending on what Database you use of course.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? What is the autoconfiguration done for JPA ?

Comment: I changed the explanation a bit. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your pom.xml I assume you are using Postgres. Make sure that in the application.properties file you configured your data source. Exception may suggest it is misconfigured.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
```